# Unable to add an OnSuccessListener for firebase storage uploadTask

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to add an OnSuccess Listener for successful upload to the firebase storage on Android. The upload to the firebase storage works like charm however when ever i try to register an onSuccessListener in get an error stating that **error: cannot find symbol class OnSuccessListener**.

Below is the code segment? I don't know what am doing wrong here. I am fairly new to Android.

```
         Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotoStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        uploadTask = photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                StorageMetadata metadata = taskSnapshot.getMetadata();
            }
        });
```